# How can I change the result shown in the same column?

Tags: python, pandas

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Identifier': ['55555-abc','77777-xyz','99999-mmm']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Identifier'])
left = df['Identifier'].str[:5]  
union = pd.concat([df,left], ignore_index=True)
print(union)
```

Result:

```
|  | Identifier  |  0  |
|--|  ---------- | --- |
|0 | 55555-abc   | NaN |
|1 | 77777-xyz   | NaN |
|2 | 99999-mmm   | NaN |
|3 |       NaN   |55555|
|4 |       NaN   |77777|
|5 |       NaN   |99999|
```

What i want:

```
|  | Identifier  | 
|--|  ---------- |
|0 | 55555-abc   |
|1 | 77777-xyz   |
|2 | 99999-mmm   | 
|3 | 55555       |
|4 | 77777       |
|5 | 99999       |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use append function from Pandas as:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Identifier': ['55555-abc','77777-xyz','99999-mmm']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Identifier'])

left = df['Identifier'].str[:5]

for i in left:
    df = df.append({'Identifier': i}, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```